# Moment Generating Function under a new probability measure

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let *Z* be a standard normal random variable under a probability measure *P*. Set *X = exp(θZ - θ<sup>2</sup>/2)*. Define a new probability measure *P<sub>1</sub>(A) = E(X 1<sub>A</sub>)*, where the expected value is taken under *P* and *1<sub>A</sub>* denotes the indicator function.

Now, let *Y = Z - θ* and find the moment generating function of *Y* under *P<sub>1</sub>* and deduce the distribution of *Y* under *P<sub>1</sub>*.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Who is $A$? $\;$

Comment: @Math1000 what does your question even mean?

Comment: @Jason Do you know who $A$ is?

Comment: A would be a set in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $E$ and $E_1$ denote expectation with respect to $P$ and $P_1$ respectively, then $E_1[W]=E[WX]$ for any random variable $W$. Apply this with $W=\exp(\lambda Y)$ to calculate the MGF of $Y$.